# i want to create a transfer table with multiple row in a single primary key

Tags: php, sql, dropdown, data-transfer, inventory-management

i have one table i want to use one primary key in many row and not stop inputting row until i finished which is one transmittal_id equals to many rows of data

example table:transfer

| (pk)transmittal_id | (fk)product_id | product_name | product_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

i want a result table like this

example result table:transfer

| transmittal_id | product_id | product_name | product_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 220526 | APCEE | 100 |
|  | 220524 | LAGUNDI | 100 |
| 1 | 220529 | TOVIT | 100 |
|  | 220601 | BETTER C | 100 |
|  | 220605 | ZINC VITA | 100 |

Comment: A primary key, by its definition, must have a unique value per row.

Answer (score 0):

If TRANSMITTAL_ID column is a PK for the TRANSFER table therefore this one cannot contain NULL values. Transmittal_id column must contain unique values for every row of the table.

Comment: this is like a one id with many row table its not a null value its for example the table but you have a one id with multiple row data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: a primary key must have a unique value. Primary key uniquely identifies each record in a table. It looks like there are duplicate values if Transmittal_id is a PK. Тhe same value cannot be inserted for more than one row. Or the PK can consist more than one column (Example: Transmittal_id, Product_name and etc.). The value of these columns is combined to create a unique identifier. Or you can create an automatically generated number - SEQUENCE for the PK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16.